# How to know that app has been paused in Android Q?

Tags: android, android-10.0

Is there any callback that the app has been paused in Android Q?
I'd like to do some actions with the app in such a case, but I can't find any descriptions of it.

"Pause app" is a new feature of Android Q:
https://9to5google.com/2019/05/21/digital-wellbeing-pixel-launch-pause-app/

It's not onPause() lifecycle method.

Comment: What's your definition of paused?

Comment: An activity is paused when **onPause()** method is called. What more do you need?

Comment: Please read the question carefully @GiddyNaya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As currently there's no official documentation for this issue, I'm posting this as an answer with hope there will be the official solution.

You can register a BroadcastReceiver with intent filter Intent.ACTION_PACKAGES_SUSPENDED. It will be triggered once you put the app to this mode.

But I'm not sure it won't have side effects or will work stable on all devices. I tried it on Pixel 2.

Answer (score 2):

For other users downvoting his question - this is about a feature in Google's [Digital Wellbeing](https://wellbeing.google/) program which has been pushed to Pixel phones - not about the activity lifecycle

For OP - I don't think you will get a satisfactory answer to this yet. I have looked through the [Android Q Beta documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview?hl=ru) and they are not offering links to anything specific. However for developers in the future, I think the term to search for is "distraction state" as mentioned in their docs:

> Per-app distraction state -- Android Q can now selectively set apps to a "distraction state" where their notifications are suppressed and they will not appear as suggested apps.

For now the only thing I can suggest is to not target android Q in gradle. So today the correct answer is **this information / api has not been made public yet**

Answer (score -1):

Currently at the time of this post. There is no documentation regarding Android Q `Pause App feature` in relation to [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) and how to apps can track this action. But based on my understanding of how `Pause App feature` works from the post i [read here](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/05/21/digital-wellbeing-lets-you-pause-apps-on-demand-straight-from-the-launcher-apk-download/) is that, all notifications from the app are disabled and also selection of the app from the launcher is also disabled.

> App paused using `Pause App feature` can still be running but can
>   neither be resumed/launched nor send new notifications.

Here is my take on what i think the `paused app` can do to verify that it is paused when targeting android Q. Though not efficient enough.

- App starts a notification during launch using [startForeground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%2520android.app.Notification)) so it won't be dismissed by the user. Showing something like `MyApp is running`.
- App uses a running [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) which regularly checks the state of the notification `every nth minutes`.
- If the service is `still running and the foreground notification is closed or cannot be found` by the service then logically we can say that the app is in a `paused state`.